# Generic factorized data helpers (system.data.commons) vs especialized data helpers (sql server) performance?

Tags: c#, performance, ado, factories

I'm planning to improve the performance of some applications. We generally use factored datahelpers (using System.Data.Common, but we are thinking to specialize some applications that are always going to use sql server.

Does anyone know or could test if is increased the performance using specialized classes instead of factorized classes?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Everyone (or nearly everyone) knows that to improve performance of a program, first you need to find out what is making it slow.

I assume you've done that.

[This is the method I use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024), and it works very well in C#. Usually there are multiple problems, and they are usually bigger than the one I have assumed is an issue.